what is a good way to setup a proxy?
I am trying to call in endpoint with an proxy setup, this is fairly straightforwrd in DEno when using createHttpClient, only is the usage of createHttpClient not possible in combination with Supabase. I tried multiple solutions to setup the proxy in fetch but have so far been unable to.
My question is mainly what is an good way to setup an proxy in this kind of setup.
My currently impleemntation is as follows:
const proxyUrl = Deno.env.get("PROXY_URL");
const proxyUsername = Deno.env.get("PROXY_USERNAME"); 
const proxyPassword = Deno.env.get("PROXY_PASSWORD");

if (!proxyUrl || !proxyUsername || !proxyPassword) {
  throw new Error("Proxy configuration is missing");
}

const proxyAuthUrl = `https://${proxyUsername}:${proxyPassword}@${proxyUrl}`;

const testUrl = ``;
const response = await this.httpClient.fetch(testUrl, {
  method: 'GET',
  proxy: proxyAuthUrl
});


You can use the environment variables HTTP_PROXY, HTTPS_PROXY, and NO_PROXY to configure such behavior. If this answers your question, I can write it as one — if not, what did I miss?

The supabase-js client just uses node-fetch, which should use Deno's Fetch API by default.  So, as @jsejcksn says, you can configure Deno itself with the environment variables.
